# LMC Loops for highest number and how many numbers (N =) (Max=)

Tags: python, loops, assembly

I am trying to implement a loop that accepts numbers as input as many as the user pleases and then prints out the biggest of it as `Max = highest number`
and `N = total number of inputs`

The program should stop when the input is `0`

This is what I have done so far but the N and Max does not print out?

```
LOOP    INP
        BRZ F
        STA first
        BRA LOOP
LOOP    INP
        BRZ F
        STA second
        BRA LOOP
        SUB second
        BRP secondBig
        LDA second
        OUT 
F       LDA \n
        OTC
        LDA N
        OTC
        LDA =
        OTC
secondBig LDA second
        LDA \n
        OTC
        LDA M
        OTC
        LDA a
        OTC
        LDA x
        OTC
        LDA =
        OTC
END     HLT
N       DAT 78
=       DAT 61
\n      DAT 10
M       DAT 77
a       DAT 97
x       DAT 120
first   DAT
second  DAT
```

Here is what im trying to do in python code

```
number = 0
max = 0
x = int(input(""))
while x != 0:
if x > max:
max = x
number = number + 1
x = int(input(""))
print("n=", number)
if number > 0:
    print("max=", max)
```

Comment: Fix indenting in your code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code doesn't run, as the indentation is off; I'll try to repair it.

Comment: it runs in LMC https://peterhigginson.co.uk/LMC/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm struggling with this one as well, but got some tips: you only need one INP. Read input, start BRZ loop and in that loop call the method that compares newinp and max (AS well as doing the counting of number of inputs in this loop).

As for my code, I can't get it to print the max, only the last input. I tried: (instead of its own INPs, it gets the ones from the read-method)

```
findMax LDA newinp    
        STA newinp
        LDA max
        STA max
        SUB newinp
        [...]
```